# Draw line as a text in wfs

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, sld

I have a WFS for addresses where geometry is a line with 2 points.
Is it possible to have an SLD that draws a text (i.e. house number) along the line using the line as vector defining the text direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know rotating text is not possible in OpenLayers. You might be able to implement something yourself if you're familiar with javascript and openlayers code, but I don't think it's easy.

It seems like someone has tried this approach, see [this ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/3651). With some luck the code provided there may work.

Answer (score 0):

There is [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#label-following-line) tutorial about it, but it says it is only for GeoServer. I hope you use GeoServer :)

Comment: I'm _not_ using GeoServer. I just use standard OpenLayers.